# How to extract a default method to the base Predicate extending java.util.function.Predicate

Tags: java, generics, predicate

I would like to implement a class hierarchy based on java.util.function.Predicate.
This is what it looks like:

```
public interface BasePredicate<T> extends Predicate<T> {
}

public interface ClientPredicate  extends BasePredicate<Client> {
    default ClientPredicate and(Predicate<? super Client> other) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(other);
        return (t) -> test(t) && other.test(t);
    }
}

public interface HomePredicate extends BasePredicate<Home> {
    default HomePredicate and(Predicate<? super Home> other) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(other);
        return (t) -> test(t) && other.test(t);
    }
}

public interface OfficePredicate extends BasePredicate<Office> {
    default OfficePredicate and(Predicate<? super Office> other) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(other);
        return (t) -> test(t) && other.test(t);
    }
}
```

I need the hierarchy because I have a method which accepts varargs of the base type - this is what its signature looks like:

```
public<T extends BasePredicate<?>> Offer getRatePlan(T... predicates) {
        ClientPredicate clientPredicate = Stream.of(predicates)
            .filter(ClientPredicate.class::isInstance)
            .map(ClientPredicate.class::cast)
            .reduce(ClientPredicate::and)
            .orElse(x -> true);

        HomePredicate homePredicate = Stream.of(predicates)
                .filter(HomePredicate.class::isInstance)
                .map(HomePredicate.class::cast)
                .reduce(HomePredicate::and)
                .orElse(x -> true);

        OfficePredicate officePredicate = Stream.of(predicates)
                .filter(OfficePredicate.class::isInstance)
                .map(OfficePredicate.class::cast)
                .reduce(OfficePredicate::and)
                .orElse(x -> true);
...
```

In it I am using the predicates to filter objects of different types in my stucture.

As you can see every predicate that extends BasePredicate provideds the default and method.
I would like to have it only in the BasePredicate but it does not work for me.
This is the last thing that I have come up with:

```
public interface BasePredicate<T> extends Predicate<T> {
    default <R extends HotelPredicate<T>> R and(Predicate<? super T> other) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(other);
        return (t) -> test(t) && other.test(t);
    }
}
```

But it does not compile, giving a message: both methods have same erasure, yet neither overrides the other.
Could you guide me on how should I approach this?
Thanks in advace!

Comment: Do you really need it isn't just the default `and` in the `Predicate` enough? Looks like you are trying to make things overly complex and if you remove the `BasePredicate` and just leave the `Predicate` and the 3 different types it would just work.

Comment: @M.Deinum, thanks for your comment. I would like to have BasePredicate as it guards against using e.g. Predicate<String> as an argument for getRatePlan method.

Comment: But it still doesn't guard you from using `BasePredicate<String>` so what is it actually adding?

Comment: Take a look at [_the the javadoc for all the JDK's different predicate interfaces_](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/package-summary.html). They're all described as: „[_specialization of Predicate_](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/IntPredicate.html)“. But if you [*look at the code for them*](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/function), none of them literally extend the actual _`Predicate`_ interface. You probably should take your cue from them.

Comment: Also I'm curious tomek. Which came first? Did you write all of those different interfaces and other classes _before_ or *after* you discovered the *`name clash`* compilation error in _`BasePredicate`_?